# Using of stream to write inside file

Tags: c++

I'm supposed to print (x,y) values inside a file called "mydata.txt". But for some reason I get the following error message: "error: can't open output file mydata.txt" I am not sure if the program is supposed to create the text file or I am supposed to create the file. I tried the latter an it still didn't work. Here is my code:

```
#include "std_lib_facilities_5.h"

class Point{
    public:

    int x;
    int y;

    // Coordinate members x and y
    Point(int nn = 0 , int mm = 0): x(nn), y(mm){}
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, const Point &point);
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Point& point){
    os << point.x << " " << point.y;
    return os;
}

int main()
try {
    int x1, x2;
    vector<Point> original_points;

    for(int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
        cout << "Please input coordinate points as (x,y): ";
        cin >> x1 >> x2;
        original_points.push_back(Point(x1,x2));
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 7; ++i){
        cout << "Original points: " << original_points[i] << endl;
    }
    string outputFile = "mydata.txt";
    ofstream ost {"mydata.txt"};
    ost.open(outputFile,ofstream::out);
    if(!ost) error("can't open output file ", outputFile);

    for(int i = 0; i < original_points.size(); ++i){
        ost << original_points[i] << " " << original_points[i];
    }
    ost.close();
}
catch (exception& e) {
    cerr << "error: " <<e.what() << '\n';
    return 1;
    }
    catch (...) {
        cerr << "Oops: unknown exception!\n";
        return 2;
    }
```

And here is the output when I run it:

```
Please input coordinate points as (x,y): 1 2
Please input coordinate points as (x,y): 1 1 
Please input coordinate points as (x,y): 2 2 
Please input coordinate points as (x,y): 3 3 
Please input coordinate points as (x,y): 4 4 
Please input coordinate points as (x,y): 5 5 
Please input coordinate points as (x,y): 6 6
Original points: 1 2
Original points: 1 1
Original points: 2 2
Original points: 3 3
Original points: 4 4
Original points: 5 5
Original points: 6 6
error: can't open output file mydata.txt
Program ended with exit code: 1
```

Comment: yes I did that. I created a filed named "mydata.txt" and put it in the same folder

Comment: @scohe001 Opening an output file stream creates the file unless you specify otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

`ofstream ost {"mydata.txt"};` opens the file.

And then your attempt to open it again in the next line fails, because it's already open.
Remove the second line.

Remove the line `ost.close();` while you're at it — the destructor will close it for you when it's time.

Comment: It's still not creating the file. Should I just make it and put in  the same directory

Comment: @PapesTraore Do you know this because your program prints an error or because you can't find it? The file should be created in the program's *working directory*, and if you're using an IDE that's usually not where your source code is.

Comment: I can't find it and do you mean the .cpp file ? I am using Xcode but I have inside a folder for my homework.

Comment: If you're running from within XCode, the default working directory is the directory where your application was built, not the directory where your source is. There's a setting somewhere, but it's easier to use an absolute path instead, like `"/Users/YourName/YourHomeworkFolder"`. Take some time to read about the *working directory* and *relative paths*.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    #include "std_lib_facilities_5.h"

class Point{
    public:

    int x;
    int y;

    // Coordinate members x and y
    Point(int nn = 0 , int mm = 0): x(nn), y(mm){}
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, const Point &point);
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Point& point){
    os << point.x << " " << point.y;
    return os;
}

int main()
try {
    int x1, x2;
    vector<Point> original_points;

    for(int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
        cout << "Please input coordinate points as (x,y): ";
        cin >> x1 >> x2;
        original_points.push_back(Point(x1,x2));
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 7; ++i){
        cout << "Original points: " << original_points[i] << endl;
    }
    ofstream ost;
    ost.open("mydata.txt");

    if(!ost) error("can't open output file ", "mydata.txt");

    for(int i = 0; i < original_points.size(); ++i){
        ost << original_points[i] << " " << original_points[i];
    }
    ost.close();
}
catch (exception& e) {
    cerr << "error: " <<e.what() << '\n';
    return 1;
    }
    catch (...) {
        cerr << "Oops: unknown exception!\n";
        return 2;
    }
```

Comment: Are we supposed to guess the difference, or could you explain what you have changed?

Comment: try just executing the code that opens the file and write a dummy message to it.  Then close the file.